# Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.3.0:run (default-cli) on project backend

Tags: java, maven, gcloud

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible and I keep getting this error. Especially when I run this command:

> mvn clean package appengine:run

I have also tried running it in Java 8 with this command:

> mvn clean package appengine:run -Djava8=true

I have also tried downgrading to Java 8, still no success.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.3.0:run (default-cli) on project backend: Failed to run devappserver: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1 -> [Help 1]

My pom.xml file is shown below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.solutions.flexenv</groupId>
  <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>App Engine Backend module for Firebase</name>
  <url>https://cloud.google.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
  </properties>
  <prerequisites>
    <maven>3.5</maven>
  </prerequisites>
  <!--
    The parent pom defines common style checks and testing strategies for our samples.
    Removing or replacing it should not affect the execution of the samples in anyway.
  -->
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>shared-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.18</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
      <artifactId>firebase-server-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>[3.0.0,)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>backend</finalName>
    <outputDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
          <webResources>
            <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
            <resource>
              <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
              <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <projectId>GCLOUD_CONFIG</projectId>
          <version>GCLOUD_CONFIG</version>
          <promote>true</promote>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Can someone please explain why this isn't working

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with Java or Maven and also don't know what is happening but runnning the commands as follows worked for me:

`sudo mvn clean package appengine:run`

Also you can try:

`sudo mvn clean package appengine:deploy`

In case it shows an error regarding that `mvn` is not found, just type the path where `mvn` is.